# What do the lighter squares in your skills mean?

Tags: the-sims-3

When playing The Sims 3 and improving your skills, one or two of the skills will have lighter squares around a certain level in the skill. So far I've only figured out that they're somehow related to my job (I think). Can anyone tell me what *exactly* these squares mean?

[image: Example of squares]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those boxes represent the level of skill required to make a promotion in your current career track easier ([source](http://forum.thesims3.com/jforum/posts/list/28767.page)).

Comment: Ah, so *easier* is the key word. I was very confused that my Sims were still getting promoted without the skill level I thought they needed. Thanks for finding that.

Comment: It is my understanding that promotions happen based on job performance (which would be affected by skill level) and happiness levels. But I haven't actually played any Sims 3 yet (though I am a veteran of 1 and 2).

Comment: The only requirement to promotions is earning enough job performance rating, but you earn it faster the better you fulfill your job's requirements.